# How to Migrate Data from Magento DB Structure to Custom Symfony App Model/Structure

Tags: symfony, magento, doctrine

I'm looking into migrating data from Magento v1.9 to a Symfony 4-based app (likely using Sylius and other bundles), and in so doing, one important question is how I would migrate data from Magento's DB structure to the new/Symfony app's model structure.

Given this, very general, theoretical question: is it possible to use, say, Doctrine's Migrations bundle to transfer data that I'm using into my own (and/or Sylius') schema?

(Much appreciate any help or suggestions!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes in a way you can use migrations, but that is not how it should be used. Doctrine Migrations is used for handling internal data changes, not importing data. If you have a system like Sylius launched and ready you should look at https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsylius/sylius-import-export-plugin
If you do not have anything setup yet, you can either try adapt doctrine entities based on Magento Database which will be pain in the ass or you could try something like https://github.com/mathielen/ImportEngineBundle on newly created scheme.